# Angular: Declare and assign property of a dependency inside constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, constructor-injection

This is a case I encounter many times during development.

Suppose I have a component with a service dependency that has some observable properties I need.

I *can* simply declare and assign them like so:

```js
files$: Observable<...>;
fileTypes$: Observable<...>;

constructor(fileService: FileService) {
  this.files$ = fileService.files$;
  this.fileTypes$ = fileService.fileTypes$;
}
```

But in cases of many properties, or where the type of the Observable(the `...` in this case) is long, this can become bloated for no good reason.

I've tried the following solution which would give me automatic type inference:

```js
constructor(fileService: FileService,
  public files$ = fileService.files$,
  public fileTypes$ = fileService.fileTypes$
) {}
```

When running, however, I get the following error:

> "Can't resolve all parameters for FilemanagerComponent: ([object Object], ?, ?)."

Adding `@Optional()` to the parameters hasn't helped.

Another solution would be to simply declare the service as `public`, then use its' property in the template, but I don't really like that solution very much as it takes away from the type safety.

Is there some clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use

```
files$ = this.fileService.files$;
fileTypes$ = this.fileService.fileTypes$;

constructor(private fileService: FileService) {}
```

But your first solution is absolutely fine. A good IDE would add the properties declarations for you with a single keyboard shortcut. And having the type declared in the component (rather than only declared in the service) makes the code easier to read and understand, IMHO.